# Personalized Page Rank

Tags: recommendation-engine, pagerank

I have been trying to wrap me head around the personalized page rank algorithm and how it works. I came across [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.04633v1.pdf) which gives this graph:[see link to image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hG6E.png) with weights calculated by PPR. I am have trouble reproducing the calculations with the models they give.

Can anyone break it down for me to help me wrap me head around the concept?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The paper is a good reference to personalized page rank. Basically my understanding, ppr scores tell you the probability from the source node move to the target node. It is a specific score describe the relationship between specific source and target nodes in the graph.

If you have problem to reproduce the results, you can use networkx in python, load a graph and compute ppr using
    networkx.pagerank(graph, personalization={'a':0, 's':1, 'b':0....})
Networkx use power iteration approach to compute ppr, you can get exact result as what shown in the example.

The author of this thesis have c++ code here https://github.com/snap-stanford/snap/blob/master/snap-core/randwalk.h  Since this method is random walk based approach, you could not get exactly same results as what shown in the example, but the rank is correct.

Hope that helps.